# Display posts with empty custom field

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

How to list post with specific custom field which is empty?

I have some posts with custom field 'author', and for some posts that custom field is emty, so I would like to find those posts to delete that custom field for them.

```
<?php 
$args=array(
'post_type' => 'post', // Post type is post.
'post_status' => 'publish', // Post is published.
'meta_key' => 'author',
'value'   => '',
'meta_compare' => '=',

'posts_per_page' => 100, // Posts per page.
'caller_get_posts'=> 100 // Get posts per page
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php // my code; ?>

<?php
endwhile;
}
?>
```

Comment: Is the field empty or not assigned. also, you are using caller_get_posts wrongly. It is deprecated and replaced by `ignore_sticky_posts`

Comment: I wish to find posts with emty fields. That custom field exist in most posts with some value, but in some posts value is emty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need the `NOT EXISTS` `meta_compare` value. This will test if a meta value exists or not for that particular key.

Also, as I pointed out in comments, `caller_get_posts`  is long time deprecated, a notice you should have clearly recieved if you had debubbing turned on. The correct parameter is `ignore_sticky_posts` and accepts `0` (*`false`*) or `1` (*`true`*)

### EDIT

One issue I missed is, `value` should be `meta_value` when not using a proper `meta_query`

Comment: I tried with NOT EXISTS meta_compare value, still I can not get posts with emty value.

Comment: One thing I missed, `value` should be `meta_value`. Try that with `meta_compare` being `=` and `NOT EXISTS`